# Batch Operations Permanent Delete (Cyclic Dependency)

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to add new batch operation where only happen in trash , the permanent delete should be running without cyclic dependency. But first , let's take a look on my `addBatchOperations` :

```
  // In lib/modules/likes/index.js
   addBatchOperations : [
    {
        name : 'delete',
        label: 'Permanent Delete',
        unlessFilter: {
            trash: false
        }
    }
   ],
```

Now , I create routes with super pattern in it. In construct :

```
var superRoutes = self.createRoutes;
self.createRoutes = function () {
    superRoutes();
    self.route('post', 'delete', self.routes.delete);
};
```

Then I create new BatchSimpleRoute :

```
self.routes.delete = function (req, res) {
    return self.batchSimpleRoute(req,'delete' , function (req, piece, data, callback) {
        console.log("req object?", req.body);
        console.log("Any Piece ?" , piece);
        return self.apos.docs.deleteFromTrash(req,callback);
    });
};
```

Then in `public/js/manager-modal.js` override , I did this :

```
// in lib/modules/likes/public/js/manager-modal.js
apos.define('apostrophe-pieces-manager-modal', {
    construct: function (self, options) {
        // calling from batchOperations {name : 'delete'} to self.batchDelete
        self.batchDelete = function () {
            return self.batchSimple(
                'delete',
                "Are you sure you want to delete " + self.choices.length + " items?", {}
            );
        };
    }
});
```

> Above code shows an error that runs `cyclic dependency detected` error. So I had done some research online, said that it needs to be run in one instead of whole document. So I dive into apostrophe node_modules code that have `self.routes.trash` , found an interesting code. Here it is , I try to implement it but it does not working.

```
self.routes.delete = function (req, res) {
    return self.batchSimpleRoute(req,'delete' , function (req, piece, data, callback) {
        console.log("req object?", req.body);
        console.log("Any Piece ?" , piece);
        var ids;
        if (req.body.job) {
            // New way
            return self.apos.modules['apostrophe-jobs'].run(req, function (req, id, callback) {
                return one(id, callback);
            });
        }

        // bc and single id case

        if (Array.isArray(req.body.ids)) {
            ids = self.apos.launder.ids(req.body.ids);
        } else {
            ids = [self.apos.launder.id(req.body._id)];
        }

        function one(id , callback){
            return async.series({
                delete : function(callback){
                    return self.apos.docs.deleteFromTrash(req, id, callback);
                }
            }, function(err){
                return callback(err);
            })
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Amin, exactlhy what happens with your second approach? It looks very close.

You didn't finish the "bc anmd single id" case though, I see you validate input but then never actually invoke "one" with that input. I don't think this has anything to do with the batch operation not working however.

Comment: Good question , it actually hangs. The modal shows a *In Progress* running a long time. I think its an infinite loop. If I cancel/stop or shut down `node app` too early. It does not successfully delete. BUT if I let it happens running without any response for , let say a one minute . I shut down the app , then restart again . It works ! But I think its the `apostrophe-jobs` kind of thing. I don't how does apostrophe-jobs do the work but I could guess that its only for a response to a front end modal, right ? Any ideas how to fix this behaviour ?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe share a project on github that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: Here [My Github ApostropheCMS Project](https://github.com/ammein/amin-website)

Comment: Please push up a project that demonstrates this one issue rather than your entire project, which you probably shouldn't have in a public repo by the way, unless your intention is to open source it.